# Is routing module can be used for calling functions that reads current routing value?

Tags: angular, typescript, service, module, angular2-routing

On Angular I would like to call some functions that will return a value according to the current page routing.
Now some of the functions are temporary placed in the element that I need to change by route's component.

I know to code those functions. My questions are:
1. Do I need to create a service such as "ColorService" for those functions?
2. Shall I call those functions from the components of the elements that I would like to change according to the routing? or from the routing module?

This is my current routing module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HomeHebComponent } from '../components/home-heb/home-heb.component';
import { AboutHebComponent } from '../components/about-heb/about-heb.component';
import { ContactHebComponent } from '../components/contact-heb/contact-heb.component';
import { GalleryComponent } from '../components/gallery/gallery.component';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { Page404Component } from '../components/page404/page404.component';
import { PlywoodHebComponent } from '../components/plywood-heb/plywood-heb.component';
import { MdfHebComponent } from '../components/mdf-heb/mdf-heb.component';
import { TegoTlatOsbHebComponent } from '../components/tego-tlat-osb-heb/tego-tlat-osb-heb.component';
import { HardwoodHebComponent } from '../components/hardwood-heb/hardwood-heb.component';
import { MapHebComponent } from '../components/map-heb/map-heb.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'heb/home', component: HomeHebComponent},
    { path: 'heb/about', component: AboutHebComponent},
    { path: 'heb/plywood1', component: PlywoodHebComponent},
    { path: 'heb/mdf', component: MdfHebComponent},
    { path: 'heb/hardwood', component: HardwoodHebComponent},
    { path: 'heb/plywood2', component: TegoTlatOsbHebComponent},
    { path: 'heb/contact', component: ContactHebComponent},
    { path: 'heb/map', component: MapHebComponent},
    { path: 'heb/gallery', component: GalleryComponent},
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/heb/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: '**', component: Page404Component }

];


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ]
})
export class RoutingModule { }
```

This is example of color changing function for the menu file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu',
  templateUrl: './menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menu.component.css']
})
export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {
    private route: string;
  constructor(location: Location, private router: Router) {
      router.events.subscribe( val => {
          if (location.path() !== '') {
              this.route = location.path();
              console.log(this.route);

      } else {
          this.route = 'home';
          console.log(this.route);

      }
    });
   }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
// switches color according to routing
  private  toggleColorAboutRouting(): string {
      return this.route === '/heb/about' ?  'white' :  'initial';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Angular Router and check the `url` property to drive that functionality in your component.

```
export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {
  private route: string;

  constructor(router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
      this.route = this.toggleColorAboutRouting(this.router.url);
  }

// switches color according to routing
  private  toggleColorAboutRouting(url: string): string {
      return this.route === '/heb/about' ?  'white' :  'initial';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can pass a data object to the route

```
{ path: 'heb/about', component: AboutHebComponent, data: {color: 'white'}},
```

and it will became:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HomeHebComponent } from '../components/home-heb/home-heb.component';
import { AboutHebComponent } from '../components/about-heb/about-heb.component';
import { ContactHebComponent } from '../components/contact-heb/contact-heb.component';
import { GalleryComponent } from '../components/gallery/gallery.component';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { Page404Component } from '../components/page404/page404.component';
import { PlywoodHebComponent } from '../components/plywood-heb/plywood-heb.component';
import { MdfHebComponent } from '../components/mdf-heb/mdf-heb.component';
import { TegoTlatOsbHebComponent } from '../components/tego-tlat-osb-heb/tego-tlat-osb-heb.component';
import { HardwoodHebComponent } from '../components/hardwood-heb/hardwood-heb.component';
import { MapHebComponent } from '../components/map-heb/map-heb.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'heb/home', component: HomeHebComponent},
    { path: 'heb/about', component: AboutHebComponent, data: {color: 'white'}},
    { path: 'heb/plywood1', component: PlywoodHebComponent},
    { path: 'heb/mdf', component: MdfHebComponent},
    { path: 'heb/hardwood', component: HardwoodHebComponent},
    { path: 'heb/plywood2', component: TegoTlatOsbHebComponent},
    { path: 'heb/contact', component: ContactHebComponent},
    { path: 'heb/map', component: MapHebComponent},
    { path: 'heb/gallery', component: GalleryComponent},
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/heb/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: '**', component: Page404Component }

];


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ]
})
export class RoutingModule { }
```

and in your comoponent you can access at data by the `ActivatedRoute`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu',
  templateUrl: './menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menu.component.css']
})
color = 'initial';
export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {
    private route: string;
  constructor(location: Location, private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute,) {
     route.data.subscribe(
       (data)=> this.color = data.color);

}
```

in the example i just set the value of a variable `color`
Edited.

Comment: If I have to implement this color data member  in the current component's html code ( I know how to ) and also in sibling component's css. Should I need to create a service for that? If I need to create a service - Will it be a better design to move the current constructor that is on "menuComponent" to the service ? Will it catch the current page location from the service?

Comment: you can move you login in a service. route.data is an observable, when you will change your route, a new value is emitted and the service can react to this new value.